# Why is my svnmerge showing up as not installed?

Tags: svn

I upgraded from 12.04 to 13.04 and in the process my svnmerge stopped working.  Synaptic tells me my subversion-tools is on 1.7.9-1+nmu6ubuntu3.  My svn is "svn, version 1.7.9 (r1462340)"

```
$ svnmerge avail
The program 'svnmerge' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install subversion-tools
```

Running the above I get a delightful

```
...
Reading state information... Done
subversion-tools is already the newest version.
...
```

What can I do to fix this? Basic svn commands seem to be working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the command-not-found data is stale. I get the same message on 13.10, but looking at the subversion-tools changelog, we see the command was removed in version 1.7.5-1.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subversion/1.7.5-1ubuntu1

```
  * Upstream no longer ships contrib in tarball:
    - Remove contrib-license-audit
    - subversion-tools now Recommends: svn2cl
    - Ship svn-clean, svn-fast-backup, svn_apply_autoprops,
      svn_load_dirs, commit-email.pl in debian/contrib
    - Don't ship svnmerge.py, it has outlived its usefulness
    - Delete patches/{svn2cl-*,svn-clean-ignore,commit-email}
    - Overhaul debian/copyright
```